# How do I place a table next to a chart?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I am doing my chemistry report where I have on the left side a graph and currently right below it the *raw* data.  I like for them both to be side to side as I am going to be putting another set and I don't want it to take up too much space.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{G1}{RGB}{198,224,180}
\definecolor{G2}{RGB}{226,239,218}
\definecolor{G3}{RGB}{112,173,71}


% snip
\part{Results}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Standard Distillation},
xlabel={Amount Collected (ml)},
ylabel={Temperature (\celsius)},
xmin=0, xmax=26,
ymin=50, ymax=100,
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
yminorgrids=true,
xminorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
mark=square,
]
coordinates {
(2,58)(4,60)(6,62)(8,63)(10,65)(12,65)(14,67)(16,69)(18,72)(20,75)(22,79)(24,88)(26,96)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% get table and chart same row, work on colour; stretching, fit above
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
{\rowcolors{3}{G1}{G2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Standard Distillation} \\
\hline
{\bf \cellcolor{G3}Amount Collected (ml)} & {\bf \cellcolor{G3}Temperature     (\celsius)} \\
\hline
2 & 58  \\
4 & 60  \\
6 & 62  \\
8 & 63  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can use two side-by-side `minipage`s:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article} 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
   \usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \definecolor{G1}{RGB}{198,224,180}
   \definecolor{G2}{RGB}{226,239,218}
   \definecolor{G3}{RGB}{112,173,71}

   \def\celsius{}% just to make the code compilable

   \begin{document}
   \part{Results}

   \noindent
   \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
   title={Standard Distillation},
   xlabel={Amount Collected (ml)},
   ylabel={Temperature (\celsius)},
   xmin=0, xmax=26,
   ymin=50, ymax=100,
   legend pos=north west,
   ymajorgrids=true,
   xmajorgrids=true,
   yminorgrids=true,
   xminorgrids=true,
   grid style=dashed,
   ]

   \addplot[
   color=blue,
   mark=square,
   ]
   coordinates {
   (2,58)(4,60)(6,62)(8,63)(10,65)(12,65)(14,67)(16,69)(18,72)(20,75)(22,79)(24,88)(26,96)
   };
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{minipage}%
   \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
   {\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
   \rowcolors{3}{G1}{G2}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Standard Distillation} \\
   \hline
   {\bf \cellcolor{G3}Amount Collected (ml)} & {\bf \cellcolor{G3}Temperature     (\celsius)} \\
   \hline
   2 & 58  \\
   4 & 60  \\
   6 & 62  \\
   8 & 63  \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}%
   }%
   \end{minipage}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. You can use a `tabular` with `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` for the `tikzpicture` (as  **Torbjørn** mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270650/how-do-i-place-a-table-next-to-a-chart/270651?noredirect=1#comment649883_270651), one can even remove the outer `tabular`):

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article} 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
   \usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \definecolor{G1}{RGB}{198,224,180}
   \definecolor{G2}{RGB}{226,239,218}
   \definecolor{G3}{RGB}{112,173,71}

   \def\celsius{}

   \begin{document}

   \part{Results}

   \noindent
   \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
   \begin{axis}[
   title={Standard Distillation},
   xlabel={Amount Collected (ml)},
   ylabel={Temperature (\celsius)},
   xmin=0, xmax=26,
   ymin=50, ymax=100,
   legend pos=north west,
   ymajorgrids=true,
   xmajorgrids=true,
   yminorgrids=true,
   xminorgrids=true,
   grid style=dashed,
   ]

   \addplot[
   color=blue,
   mark=square,
   ]
   coordinates {
   (2,58)(4,60)(6,62)(8,63)(10,65)(12,65)(14,67)(16,69)(18,72)(20,75)(22,79)(24,88)(26,96)
   };
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   &
   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
   \rowcolors{3}{G1}{G2}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Standard Distillation} \\
   \hline
   {\bf \cellcolor{G3}Amount Collected (ml)} & {\bf \cellcolor{G3}Temperature     (\celsius)} \\
   \hline
   2 & 58  \\
   4 & 60  \\
   6 & 62  \\
   8 & 63  \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Which is the **better** way so to speak?  I tried the second method first, got a "booboo" according to the error, but it allowed me to continue.

Comment: @JonWeinraub What do you mean with a "booboo"? My code doesn't produce errors. Both approaches are valid. In the second one you don't have to explicitly provide widths, as in the first one.

Comment: Sorry about the Celsius I think it is in `\usepackage{gensymb}` i took out a few things I thought to be unnecessary (from the title page)

Comment: Nevermind on the booboo, it was me.  I kept the close table, I had more closes than opens.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Simpler: remove the outer `tabular` altogether from the second suggestion.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. True. I added a remark about this. Thanks.